# How to point Google Cloud Vision API credential key file to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable in yii2 framework

Tags: php, api, yii2, cloud, vision

I want to use Google Cloud Vision API for image recognition, Everything installed fine in my yii2 framework.

I'm getting authentication error like :

```
>  Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException
>     {
>     "error": {
>     "code": 403,
>     "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
>     "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
>     }
>     }
>     1. in C:\xampp\htdocs\vofms\vendor\google\cloud-core\src\RequestWrapper.php
> at line 336
>     32732832933033133233333433533633733
```

How to point my key.json file to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable In yii2 framework.

Thanks

Comment: which yii2 extension are you using for the API? please mention the link

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-vision

Comment: were you able to solve the problem? or still stuckup somewhere with it.

Answer (score 1):

The point you are failing is the Authentication as you are looking at the Cloud Vision library whereas the Cloud Vision is a part of the [Google Cloud PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php) in which you have the [Authentication Guide](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php#authentication) given which recommends the following.

Once you've obtained your credentials file, it may be used to create an authenticated client.

```
use Google\Cloud\Core\ServiceBuilder;

// Authenticate using a keyfile path
$cloud = new ServiceBuilder([
    'keyFilePath' => 'path/to/keyfile.json'
]);

// Authenticate using keyfile data
$cloud = new ServiceBuilder([
    'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/keyfile.json'), true)
]);
```

If you do not wish to embed your authentication information in your application code, you may also make use of [Application Default Credentials.](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials)

```
use Google\Cloud\Core\ServiceBuilder;

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/keyfile.json');

$cloud = new ServiceBuilder();
```

The `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable may be set in your server configuration.

#### LINUX OR MACOS

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
```

For example:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"
```