# { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }

Tags: laravel, google-vision

I am trying to use google vision API for the image to text converter. I don't know how to use key.json file in the controller. can someone assist?

```
if($request->file('image')){
        //convert image to base64
            $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('image')));
            //Sending image for OCR server
            $vision = new VisionClient(['keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents("key.json"), true)]);
            $familyPhotoResource = fopen($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 'r');
            $image = $vision->image($familyPhotoResource,
                [
                 'DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION'
                ]);
            $result = $vision->annotate($image);
            dd($result);
      }
```

Comment: you may have to be more specific to the path of key.json  file_get_contents( storage_path('key.json)) assuming the key is in /storage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to point Google Cloud Vision API credential key file to GOOGLE\_APPLICATION\_CREDENTIALS variable in yii2 framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605435/how-to-point-google-cloud-vision-api-credential-key-file-to-google-application-c)

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check that VisionClient credentials.json file is accessible you can check buy dumping like

```
dd(json_decode(file_get_contents('credentials.json'), true));
```

if output is look like this then its mean file is accessible https://i.stack.imgur.com/EThux.png

if still not working then try this

try{

```
    $vision = new VisionClient(['keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents('credentials.json'), true)]);

    $image  = $vision->image($IMAGE_URL,['Text_Detection']);
    $annotation = $vision->annotate($image);
    $textAnnotations = $annotation->info();

    if( isset($textAnnotations['textAnnotations']) )
    foreach ($textAnnotations['textAnnotations'] as $key => $textAnnotation) {
        $image_text = $textAnnotation['description'];
        break;
    }

    dd($image_text);

}catch(\Exception $e){

    dd("Text Not Detected!");

}
```